# Number of distinguishable sequences in a graph-coloring game

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colorings

This is an extended version of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2211048/counting-permissible-sequences-in-a-graph-coloring-game), more carefully presented for professional mathematicians.

---

Consider a two-player game on the complete undirected graph $K_5$, in which edges are initially uncolored.  Player A chooses an uncolored edge and colors it blue, then player B chooses an uncolored edge and colors it red.  Players alternate until one player (the loser) is forced to have colored three edges forming a triangle with the same color.  (Such a game can end in a draw, as $K_5$ can be expressed as the union of two 5-cycles, as Gerhard Paseman points out.)  Assume that on each move a player avoids completing such a triangle, if possible.

**Questions**

- How many distinguishable games are there?  Two games are distinguishable if there is no permutation of the vertex labels (and hence edge labels) that yields the same sequence of moves.
- What is the discrete distribution of total moves in distinguishable games, assuming each valid game is equally likely?
- One can use Ramsey theory to count the number of end configurations that end in a draw.  What is the number of distinguishable *games* than end in a loss for player A, loss for player B, or draw?
- Generalize the above to $K_n$ for arbitrary $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

Comment: Uh, $K_5$ can end in a draw as it is the union of two 5 cycles.  Look up Ramsey numbers to see $R(3,3)=6$.  Gerhard "It's A Problem Of Friendship" Paseman, 2017.03.31.

Comment: You are correct.  Thank you.  I'll change the problem accordingly.

Comment: The $K_5$ game plays can almost be enumerated by hand, especially if you stop when a triangle is formed. I get 1 game for 1 move, 2 for 2 moves, 7 for 3 edges picked.  This leaves less than 5040 continuations for each of the 7 cases, and it is likely a tenth of that.  Have you tried hand enumeration?  Gerhard "I Don't Mean Finger Counting" Paseman, 2017.03.31.

Comment: "Assume on each move a player avoids completing such a triangle, if possible."